# What determines who gets the block reward

Tags: mining, block-reward, coinbase-transaction, transactions

I am trying to understand the monero code and was unsure how the code decides which address to the block reward to and how it is done. I have been able to follow the proccess up until we decide how much the block reward is but after that I havent been able to follow the code to see how it actually creates the transaction and sends it.

Answer (score 1):

In the miner code, there is [a `request_block_template` function](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/c413613416fa6656cbe9aa9fca43d8ea1251a202/src/cryptonote_basic/miner.cpp#L130), which requests a new block template to the daemon using the miner's address.

If and when the miner finds a block, she will create it from the block template that contains her address. If the block is accepted by the network, her address will be credited with the block reward.

Comment: But let's say I wanted to change the coinbase transaction so that 1% of the block reward would go to the dev fund how would that work.

Comment: You can't - the reward is paid in full to the coinbase address that is included in the block. If you want to pay the dev fund, you need to make a separate payment.

Comment: So even if we hard forked monero there would no possibility to create a dev fund by modifying the code

Comment: It would probably not be trivial change but there is no reason why you wouldn't be able to do that. I don't know the code enough to say how hard it would be.

Comment: @assylias does that mean the coinbase address is visible in clear text (not stealth) so it's publicly known who (the coinbase address) received how much (block reward + fees)? Would this allow any kind of tracking?

Comment: No it uses a stealth address.

Comment: While the monero RPC doesn't allow this, you can technically create a coinbase tx with more than one output.

Comment: @user36303 do you know function we would have to modify in order to force this

Comment: construct_miner_tx